# CSS Sprite does not render correct in browser

Tags: html, css, sprite

Here is my Sprite:
http://crystalise.tw/crystaliseTW/icons/sprite.png

When I try it on a website like here:  http://crystalise.tw

It is not shown properly when I use Firefox and Chromium browser.

What can the problem be ?

This is from my CSS:

```
.sprite { background: url('../icons/sprite.png') no-repeat top left; width: 64px; height: 64px;  } 
.sprite.blogger { background-position: 0px 0px;  } 
.sprite.flickr { background-position: 0px -64px;  } 
.sprite.github { background-position: 0px -128px;  } 
.sprite.heart { background-position: 0px -192px;  } 
.sprite.linkedin { background-position: 0px -256px;  } 
.sprite.magnolia { background-position: 0px -320px;  } 
.sprite.pinterest { background-position: 0px -384px;  } 
.sprite.skype { background-position: 0px -448px;  } 
.sprite.so { background-position: 0px -512px;  } 
.sprite.youtube_64 { background-position: 0px -576px;  }
```

Comment: Where can i find the `Chromium` browser? Which browser is it working properly in?

Comment: Not working properly in Opera either. Can you please paste entire HTML and CSS so we can take a proper look at it ? Your CSS doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your nav is only 700px wide.
You have 10 nav items that are each 64px (width) + 22px (margin) wide, this totals to 860px wide, 160px too large.
I'd recommend decreasing the right-margin of nav > div elements, or increasing the width of your nav.
Lastly, your last div in the nav probably doesn't need a right-margin, so use something like this:
    nav > div:last-child {
        margin-right: 0;
    }

Comment: Thank you !  I would never have thought about that myself!  ^_^